# Notification in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vs-extensibility

I need to troubleshoot my project automatically when the project is built.
i.e:
I have referred some assemblies in my project.i need to refer those assemblies in some other part of my project such as web.config file. if i missed any reference there i need to be notified by Visual studio while compilation. Any ways to achieve this? how to notify Visual Studio Dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/dchestnutt/archive/2006/05/30/80113.aspx).  In your prebuild, you can add a script that checks for the existence of that file.  If it doesn't find it, then you call exit 1, which halts the build.  Accompany that with an echo of some sort and you have the makings of a simple check and notification in Visual Studio during your build.